# Asset URL's return nothing in Craft 3

Tags: templating, assets, craft3

I have an Assets field assigned to my homepage. I can assign and upload images the same way I've always done.

When it comes to templating, I can loop through the images and output the filename. What I can't do anymore is get the URL. What am I missing?

```
{% set assets = entry.featured %}

{% if assets | length %}

    <h3>Some great assets</h3>
    {% for asset in assets %}
        <p>
          {{ asset.title }}<br />
          {{ asset.url }}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

The url's no longer return anything. I've also tried getUrl('someTransformHandle') too.

I can't see anything mentioned in the [Craft 3 documentation for assets](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/assets.md) regarding any deprecations or significant changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set up your Asset Volumes to have the proper paths/URLs? Do you have `Assets in this volume have public URLs` turned on?

Do you have a `volumes.php` configured to be multi-environment aware? It's not a necessary step, unless you require the now-deprecated `environmentVariables` settings:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases